# T-SQL connector for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Is there any way to use T-SQL queries with MySQL database, like having a data connector that understand TSQL and can connect to MySQL?

Comment: you mean how to make MySql as a linked server on MS sql?

Comment: You'd still have to use MySQL syntax within the `OPENQUERY()` statement. I don't think this is possible, fundamentally you always have to use MySQL's syntax to query the database. You may be able to use another product as a visualisation or interpretation layer, but the base query would have to be MySQL. i.e. TSQL Specific syntax could not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

By the time you've developed or found an interface that could translate T-SQL syntax into MySQL (correctly); you might as well have learnt the syntax required to write the MySQL you need.

It's not all that different to be honest; and it will broaden your knowledge and make you flexible for other types of database query languages.